# NLog - DDL for Log Table and Setting the ConnectionString Programmatically

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, logging, nlog

**1:**

Is there a create statement for the Database Target Log Table for all the possible fields documented somewhere? I created one by guessing and I could check the source, but it would be handy if the generic SQL was available.  I searched StackOverflow and the NLog site, but the SQL I found was dated and contained incorrect field types.

**2:**

If you're configuring a database target from a nlog.config file, how do you programmatically set the connection string?  Something like:

Logger dbLogger = LogManager.GetLogger("dbLogger");
DatabaseTarget t = dbLogger.GetDatabaseTarget;
t.ConnectionString = "...";

in application_start.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Same question is answered here](http://nlog-forum.1685105.n2.nabble.com/DDL-for-Database-Table-How-to-set-Connection-String-Programmatically-td5241103.html)

Answer (score 0):

Is this below sample helpful to you? I found this in nlog site. Have you tried this?

```
<target xsi:type="Database" name="db">
      <!-- SQL command to be executed for each entry -->
      <commandText>INSERT INTO [LogEntries](TimeStamp, Message, Level, Logger) VALUES(getutcdate(), @msg, @level, @logger)</commandText>

      <!-- parameters for the command -->
      <parameter name="@msg" layout="${message}" />
      <parameter name="@level" layout="${level}" />
      <parameter name="@logger" layout="${logger}" />

      <!-- connection string -->
      <dbProvider>System.Data.SqlClient</dbProvider>
      <connectionString>server=.\SQLEXPRESS;database=MyLogs;integrated security=sspi</connectionString>

      <!-- commands to install database -->
      <install-command>
        <text>CREATE DATABASE MyLogs</text>
        <connectionString>server=.\SQLEXPRESS;database=master;integrated security=sspi</connectionString>
        <ignoreFailures>true</ignoreFailures>
      </install-command>

      <install-command>
        <text>
          CREATE TABLE LogEntries(
          id int primary key not null identity(1,1),
          TimeStamp datetime2,
          Message nvarchar(max),
          level nvarchar(10),
          logger nvarchar(128))
        </text>
      </install-command>

      <!-- commands to uninstall database -->
      <uninstall-command>
        <text>DROP DATABASE MyLogs</text>
        <connectionString>server=.\SQLEXPRESS;database=master;integrated security=sspi</connectionString>
        <ignoreFailures>true</ignoreFailures>
      </uninstall-command>
    </target>
```